# Как сформулировать путь до файла в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, файлы, path

Прошу помощи! Я никак не могу сформулировать относительный путь к файлу script/mathFunction.js, чтобы воспользоваться им в файле components/Main/ResponseWindow.jsx
Что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ../script/mathFunction.js

Comment: Не получилось, скриншот прикреплю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю скрин, вам нужно подняться на три каталога выше (в `Main`, потом в `components`, потом в `src`) и потом уже искать каталог `script`. Если так, попробуйте `../../../script/mathFunction.js`.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает